# How can you add e.g. 'gm' to a regex to avoid repeating the full regex again?

Tags: javascript, regex, dry

I would like to define two regexs where the only difference is that one is global/multiline while the other is not.

How can I define them so that I don't have to repeat the full regex, i.e. use the first as a variable?

```
const regex1 = /(\[.*?\])/;
// const regex2 = /(\[.*?\])/gm;
const regex2 = regex1 + 'gm'; // error
```

Comment: `const regex2 = new RegExp(regex1, 'gm')`

Comment: Sorry, string concatenation actually works (I had a typo) as does `const regex2 = \`${regex1}gm\`` but your solution is cleaner, thanks.

Comment: Since there are no anchors in your pattern, you don't need the m modifier, but perhaps it's only an example.